# Plot inside Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using IPython notebooks to share code and (hopefully) graphics with m collaborators. sadly, I cannot get matplotlib to plot inside the notebook, it always gives me a pop-up window, which I obviously cannot include in [notebook pastes](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/) or similar.

Here's two minimal examples of how I go about plotting things.

Either [with invoking `plt.show()`](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/8606917/raw/2a93b8b1c3b15e8467cca21b5924c20533787fc5/imFreq?create=1) , or [without it](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/8606917/raw/6c71307954e6a0829b8713358d2d5427e49f2de3/imFreq?create=1).

this either gives me an external pop-up, or plots nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to be using the [matplotlib inline backend](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/notebook.html#plotting).

```
%matplotlib inline
```